# Why is my (guile) scheme macro evaluating its argument?

Tags: scheme, guile, syntax-rules

Within Guile, I am trying to learn `define-syntax` and `syntax-rules`.  I was under the impression that scheme macros do not evaluate their arguments, but it seems like mine is doing so:

```
(define-syntax foo
    (syntax-rules ()
        ((foo word)
            (if (eqv? word 'bar) (begin (write "Caller said BAR!") (newline)))
            )))
```

If I call it with `(foo bar)`, I get the error message

> Unbound variable: bar

Whereas if I call it with `(foo 'bar)`, I get the expected

> "Caller said BAR!"

This makes it seem as though the argument is getting evaluated prior to application of the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and look at what the macro expansion is first:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (use-modules (language tree-il))
scheme@(guile-user)> (tree-il->scheme (macroexpand '(foo bar)))
```

indented edited for clarity

```lisp
(if ((@@ (#{ g184}#) eqv?) bar (quote bar))
    (begin ((@@ (#{ g184}#) write) "Caller said BAR!")
       ((@@ (#{ g184}#) newline))))
```

So `(foo bar)` is transformed into(after removing `@@`s):

```
(if (eqv? bar (quote bar))
    (begin (write "Caller said BAR!")
       (newline)))
```

before evaluation happens. Now the error makes sense doesn't it?

Now what happens if you quote the `word` parameter? See how this expands:

```lisp
(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((foo word)
     (if (eqv? 'word 'bar) (begin (write "Caller said BAR!") (newline))))))
```

Comment: I think so, yes.  Essentially: the surprise evaluation was happening at runtime, not macro-expansion time?
And, I think this means that if I want my syntax to allow unquoted arguments, then I'll need to change my if-condition to `(eqv? (quote word) 'bar)` ?

Comment: Yes. When debugging always check the macro expansion first. You need to be sure when the bug is, during expansion or evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging method.